# Laravel stop running for some times

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

please I have deployed Laravel project to a cPanel, but when the laravel website is not visited for few hours, I revisited the website and it was loading long before it showed its contents. Is there any way I can use to make the laravel website running always?

Comment: You probably have a heavy or unoptimized query on the home page and it is only cached for a few hours.

Comment: Okay I see. I will figure it out. Thanks

Comment: or your project have so many autoloads that slows down require/include, and the opcache is only for a few hour

Comment: or the hosting provider shut the server down your plan (maybe free tier), then just turn it on again when some request got in

Comment: The hosting plan is not free I purchased recently.

Comment: either way, you can use free cron service like https://cron-job.org/ to generate traffic to your site periodically to keep them 'hot' (e.g.: keeping cache from being evicted) / tho I don't know if its allowed by your hosting provider

Comment: Cron-job.org? Will look into it later thanks.